# console.log is "cheating"? How do I get REAL output from console.log?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, I noticed a strange behavior. I am working on a ReactJS app that generates SVG outputs. The crux on the matter is that I want to embed the ReactJS into a CMS and the CMS is sending data to the ReactJS and React is supposed load fonts via opentype.js and to generate paths from the opentype.js object, then deliver the SVG as soon as it's rendered. For that I created an array of promises that gets fulfilled as soon as all data is received and all fonts are loaded.

For that I created a class-based component as sort of an "API" that provides functions via `window.api.myFunction()`, which can be called in a javascript provided by the CMS.

```
constructor() {
  super();
  window.api = this;
}

setText(t) {
  const context = this.context;
  context.handleTextInput(t).then((result) => {
    console.log("setText context.svgString:", context.svgString);
    return context.svgString;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("setText error:", err);
    return false;
  });
}
```

The `context.svgString` contains a ref to the SVG element that's generated. The console log here prints out the correct SVG string containing paths for the text when I call `window.api.setText({sometextobject...})` in the dev tools window BUT, it is not really there when console.log is called. If I try to access the return value of that function, it's in it's initial state (the SVG without paths, the paths are supposed to be generated within ReactJS.

It seems that console.log is just pulling the needed data from the page as soon as ReactJS finishes rendering and does NOT really print out what's in the variable at the time when **console.log** is called.

I counter-checked this in vscode with running a debugger and putting a breakpoint on the return `context.svgString` on the ReactJS app and in the debugger I see, that the SVG is empty and not generated, despite console.log happily printing out the correct result.

This left me baffled because there are times when I need to rely on console.log giving me the correct **output at the time** when it's called and not when it "thinks" it can display something.

Does anyone know something about this behavior? Is this normal/intended? Because if so then console.log can not really be used for debugging. This happens in latest Firefox as well as in Chromium.

Comment: Put `context.svgString` into the string which is logged? `console.log(\`setText context.svgString: ${context.svgString}\`)`

Comment: that would contain an empty string. Ok fair enough this solves the issue console log not giving the correct data when called.

Comment: Console logs of objects are updated. The default workaround is to stringify it. But the execution flow here isn't clear at all since the `then` doesn't use its `result` parameter and we have no way of knowing how `context.svgString` is being generated, or, more importantly, **when**. It's likely there's some async mismatches going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning inside the `then` and `catch` *callback*, not from `setText` itself. You are basically doing:

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        return 42; // DOES NOT RETURN FROM 'foo'
    }
}

console.log(foo()); // undefined
```

You have to return the promise:

```
setText(t) {
  const context = this.context;
  return context.handleTextInput(t).then((result) => {
    console.log("setText context.svgString:", context.svgString);
    return context.svgString;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("setText error:", err);
    return false;
  });
}
```

and when you call `setText`, you have to wait for it to resolve to get the result:

```
window.api.setText("my cool text").then((result) => { /* ... */ });
// or using ES6 async/await
const result = await window.api.setText("my cool text");
```

You should also use ES6 async/await if you can for the body of `setText`:

```
setText(t) {
  const context = this.context;

  try {
    const result = await context.handleTextInput(t);
    console.log("setText context.svgString:", context.svgString);
    return context.svgString;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("setText error:", err);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try the solution. evolutionxbox who commented to my question said that I should try putting the variable into the string, and if I do that the variable is empty. So I need to see if the return variable is empty here too.

Comment: @user6329530 We don't know how `context.svgString` is being set so there's no way to know why it's empty, and it's confusing that `result` is ignored.